# cakePHP & nuSOAP, redirects to app/webroot and does not hit controller/method, why?

Tags: cakephp, soap, routes, nusoap

I'm using CakePHP Version: 1.2.10
with NuSOAP Version: 0.9.5

I have the Service working under an application not written in Cakephp (Old procedural code).
I am wanting to move the service under my cakePHP app.

The old website is hosted on subdomain: `www.`
The old service (which works as expected) is located at:

```
<!-- old Procedural code -->
http://www.mysite.org.uk/services/donations.php
```

---

The CakePHP website is hosted on subdomain: `new.`
The new service (for which the code is almost exactly the same!) is located at:

```
<!-- CakePHP - SOAP response doesn't reach here?, redirects to app/webroot -->
http://new.mysite.org.uk/services/registerDonation/
```

**The Problem**
- When cakePHP receives a response, instead of going to `controller/action` (`services/registerDonation`, in this case). It goes to `app/webroot` (which returns the sender to the homepage (which obviously can't process the SOAP response and respond).

... So the Request Fails... `:(`

Obviously this is a issue with cakePHP & how it routes requests, but im stuck on how to find any way around this? (`noob@cakePHP`).

Would `.htaccess`?! or a custom cakePHP `route`?! do the job?, If so how can I implement this?

**To Summarise..**
How do I get a SOAP request from an external server to hit the  `services/registerDonation` [`controller/method`] in cakePHP.

If any more info is required, just shout and leave a message.

Comment: are U using ACL in cakePHP app ? If so dont forget to allow public access to services/registerDonation

Comment: No i dont have a services model, Its not required, I have a donations model (but this can't be the issue because its not hitting the `services/registerDonation` controller/method).
I have the following in my config.php:
`Configure::write('Acl.classname', 'DbAcl');`
`Configure::write('Acl.database', 'default');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you need services model:

```
class Services extends AppModel {
   public $name = 'Services';
   public $useTable = false;
}
```

If it's not there, cake also won't see your services controller...

Answer (score 0):

Tell me that you don't happen to have a services folder  in your webroot. It happend to me once... That would just show you this folders content and nothin else

Comment: No, No services folder in the webroot, my webroot has CSS, JS, IMG & Files folders only. No services folder.